# Replace list items with jQuery except first, last

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I have a list of items where the first and last act as navigation buttons, so when ajax loads new content, the middle items must be replaced with the new HTML retrieved.

```
<ul>
  <li class="photonav">Older Photos</li>
  <li class="photo">Item to replace</li>
  <li class="photo">Item to replace</li>
  <li class="photo">Item to replace</li>
  <li class="photonav">Newer Photos</li>
</ul>
```

The items with class `photo` must be replaced with the HTML items just got (pre-armed HTML list items). The `photonav` items must remain untouched.

I know I can remove them with the `.photo` selector, but how do I place new HTML code between the navigation items?

Comment: How are you retrieving your new HTML and how does it looks like? (I mean it's just the inner LI's content or a whole new bunch of LI+content elements?)

Comment: My new HTML comes from an ajax request and is in a javascript variable. It is pre-armed, in the form of concatenated <li></li> items. Please don't downvote my question or explain why someone is downvoting without reason, that's unfair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the inner elements by simply selecting them and removing them:

```
$('.photo').remove();
```

At that point you have this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="photonav">Older Photos</li>
  <li class="photonav">Newer Photos</li>
</ul>
```

Then your next step is to insert content after the first `li`, correct?  Then insert the content `after()` the `first()` element:

```
$('.photonav').first().after(someContent);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `<div>` to the list.

```
<ul>
  <li class="photonav">Older Photos</li>
  <div class="insert">
  <li class="photo">Item to replace</li>
  <li class="photo">Item to replace</li>
  <li class="photo">Item to replace</li>
  </div>
  <li class="photonav">Newer Photos</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Not according to the spec of a `ul`, though.

Comment: Thanks but I already had that idea, is not very elegant and may have unexpected results in older browsers. I'm looking for a more orthodox method.

Comment: Thanks for that Andrew and alex. I just tested it out in Chrome and seemed to work fine, I'll avoid using divs in ul from now on though

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do

```
$('.photo').remove();
$('.photonav').last().before(newcontent)
```